# Make a smooth transition to items inside a container

Tags: css, css-animations

I would like to bring "Hello world" inside a white container from left to right but I don't want the container to move.

Need to move just text and the text flashes from left to right like a quick slider movement pleasing to the eye.

How to achieve this using CSS animation?

```css
body {
  background: red
}

.container {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for making the animation use `@keyframes`

and for making the text not visible if outside use `overflow`

`forwards` for saving the last keyframes of animation.

```css
body {
  background: red
}

.container {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.container {
  overflow: auto; /* use "hidden" instead if it shows a unnecessary scrollbar. */
}

h1 {
  animation: toRight 0.2s ease-in forwards;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

@keyframes toRight {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. Any reason why you are adding container overflow:auto?

Comment: @Indiestartupman yes, so the text not be show on red background, only white. this is working fine since the animation start from left to right, but if animation is right to left then use `overflow: hidden` so won't trigger a automatic scrollbar.

Comment: How to speed up the movement from left to right. I want to make the movement quick?

Comment: @Indiestartupman just change the seconds value, ❌`1s` ✅`0.2s` `animation: toRight 0.2s ease-in forwards;` hope it solve your bug. have a nice day!